# Segmentation Fault while freeing memory in C

Tags: c, pointers, memory, integer, free

So I'm running the program to overcome integer overflow and while i'm debugging it runs through the first command hugePrint(p = parseString("12345")); without an issue. It runs the code after,   hugeDestroyer(p); and frees the memory without a problem. Once I run the next line of code in Ubuntu i'm getting a seg fault and it won't even print the numbers but on windows it prints "354913546879519843519843548943513179" and then gives me a seg fault after it runs hugeDestroyer(p); again. Also Having problems running a NULL value through my parseString() function. Any help is greatly appreciated to shed light on the seg faults.

```
// main
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include "Fibonacci.h"

// print a HugeInteger (followed by a newline character)
void hugePrint(HugeInteger *p)
{
    int i;

    if (p == NULL || p->digits == NULL)
    {
        printf("(null pointer)\n");
        return;
    }

    for (i = p->length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        printf("%d", p->digits[i]);
    printf("\n");
}

int main(void)
{
    HugeInteger *p;

    hugePrint(p = parseString("12345"));
    hugeDestroyer(p);

    hugePrint(p = parseString("354913546879519843519843548943513179"));
    hugeDestroyer(p);

    hugePrint(p = parseString(NULL));
    hugeDestroyer(p);

    hugePrint(p = parseInt(246810));
    hugeDestroyer(p);

    hugePrint(p = parseInt(0));
    hugeDestroyer(p);

    hugePrint(p = parseInt(INT_MAX));
    hugeDestroyer(p);

    hugePrint(p = parseInt(UINT_MAX));
    hugeDestroyer(p);

    return 0;
}

//fibonacci.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include "Fibonacci.h"


// Functional Prototypes
/*
HugeInteger *hugeAdd(HugeInteger *p, HugeInteger *q)
{

}
*/


HugeInteger *hugeDestroyer(HugeInteger *p)
{
    int i;
    if ( p == NULL )
        return NULL;

    if( p->length != NULL)
        free(p->length);

    if ( p->digits != NULL )
    {
        for ( i = 0; i < p->length; i++)
            free( p->digits[i] );
        free( p->digits );
    }
    free( p );

    return NULL;

}

HugeInteger *parseString(char *str)
{

    int counter, reverseCount = 0;
    HugeInteger *numArray = malloc(sizeof(HugeInteger));

    if ( str == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
//checks for NULL pointer
    if ( numArray == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

// Dynamically allocate memory for array of numbers
    numArray->length = strlen(str);
    numArray->digits = malloc( sizeof(int) * numArray->length+1);

    if ( numArray->digits == NULL)
        return NULL;

    for( counter = numArray->length - 1 ; counter >= 0 ; counter--)
    {
        numArray->digits[reverseCount] = str[counter];

// Handles conversion from ASCII to integer format
        switch(numArray->digits[reverseCount])
        {
        case 48:
            numArray->digits[reverseCount] = 0;
            break;
        case 49:
            numArray->digits[reverseCount] = 1;
            break;
        case 50:
            numArray->digits[reverseCount] = 2;
            break;
        case 51:
            numArray->digits[reverseCount] = 3;
            break;
        case 52:
            numArray->digits[reverseCount] = 4;
            break;
        case 53:
            numArray->digits[reverseCount] = 5;
            break;
        case 54:
            numArray->digits[reverseCount] = 6;
            break;
        case 55:
            numArray->digits[reverseCount] = 7;
            break;
        case 56:
            numArray->digits[reverseCount] = 8;
            break;
        case 57:
            numArray->digits[reverseCount] = 9;
            break;
        default:
            numArray->digits[reverseCount] = 0;
            break;
        }
        reverseCount++;
    }

    return numArray;

}

HugeInteger *parseInt(unsigned int n)
{
    HugeInteger *number = malloc(sizeof(HugeInteger));
    if( number == NULL )
        return NULL;

    if(n > UINT_MAX )
        return NULL;

    number = n;

    return number;

}
unsigned int *toUnsignedInt(HugeInteger *p)
{
    unsigned int *newInteger = malloc(sizeof(unsigned int));

    if( newInteger == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    if (p == NULL || p > UINT_MAX )
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    newInteger = p;

    return newInteger;

}
/*
HugeInteger *fib(int n)
{
    // base cases: F(0) = 0, F(1) = 1
    if (n < 2)
        return n;
// definition of Fibonacci: F(n) = F(n – 1) + F(n - 2)
    return fib(n – 1) + fib(n – 2);
}
*/

//fibonacci.h
#ifndef __FIBONACCI_H
#define __FIBONACCI_H

typedef struct HugeInteger
{
    // a dynamically allocated array to hold the digits of a huge integer
    int *digits;

    // the number of digits in the huge integer (approx. equal to array length)
    int length;
} HugeInteger;


// Functional Prototypes

HugeInteger *hugeAdd(HugeInteger *p, HugeInteger *q);

HugeInteger *hugeDestroyer(HugeInteger *p);

HugeInteger *parseString(char *str);

HugeInteger *parseInt(unsigned int n);

unsigned int *toUnsignedInt(HugeInteger *p);

HugeInteger *fib(int n);


#endif
```

Comment: I've removed the 
    'free(p->length)'
thank you for pointing that out. I've noticed that at run time the program is not freeing past 10 indexes of p->digits[i] within the for loop which is bringing up my seg fault

Comment: Check my edit to see why it does not go pass 10 indexes.

Comment: You are illegally interchanging pointers and integers all over the place. The compiler should be spewing warnings at you. Pay attention to them!  Also, how can an `unsigned int` ever be greater than `UINT_MAX`?  Also also, why use a `switch` to implement a linear function?  Try `d = (c >= '0' && c <= '9') ? c - '0' : 0`

Comment: I will definitely try that ternary, looks much more simple. The purpose of the (n > UINT_MAX) is to not allow the user to input a number larger than the max, instead I'm simply to return null

Comment: But the argument is an `unsigned int`, so by definition, it cannot hold a value greater than `UINT_MAX`, since `UINT_MAX` is defined to be the largest value that can be held in an `unsigned int`.

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple problems in your code.

When you `malloc` to get a HugeInteger, you don't initialize the memory returned to 0. Since you have early return in your method when `str == NULL`, members of the struct aren't initialized so when you call hugeDestroyer on it, you get undefined behavior because you don't know what memory looks like in your struct. More than likely p->digits is not null and it tries to free memory from it.

In hugeDestroyer you have this code

```
if( p->length != NULL)
    free(p->length);
```

length is an int and is not dynamically allocated with malloc so calling free on this interprets the int as an address. Undefined behavior again.

Also in hugeDestroyer, you have this code

```
for ( i = 0; i < p->length; i++)
    free( p->digits[i] );
free( p->digits );
```

This is also wrong, `p->digits` is allocated once with the right size. You only need to call `free(p->digits)` since c runtime remember the size of allocation. Your seg fault is again caused by free interpreting values in digits array as memory addresses to free.

Comment: +1 You made me realize how rusty my plain C skills have gotten =).

Comment: Wow I did not realize that, I was under the impression I needed to free each index.
That worked to get me past the free of the large array but seg faults when HugeDestroyer() is called on a NULL value

Comment: @Chris.r.Torres What compiler are you using. I had to fix lots of error especially the parseInt function where you assign an int value to a pointer again. If I remove parseInt method and apply fixes I suggested, everything runs fine on my side.

Comment: I'm using Codeblocks. I know I have errors within the parseInt() function I'm just having a hard time pin pointing it. When I debug it seg faults after running the value 246810 through parseInt() and calling hugePrint() in the main

Comment: `parseInt` is horribly broken.  You are overwriting the pointer with the integer, and returning it as a pointer. Fix all the compiler warnings!!

Comment: thanks @pat I see what you mean about overwriting the pointer.

Comment: @Chris.r.Torres Can your class holds negative values ? Also I am not sure how you want to store the int in hugeinteger when you parse it.

Comment: @EricFortin
-none of the values can be negative
-if NULL return NULL
-if value greater than INT_MAX return NULL

Comment: Well looks like @pat got you covered for the parseInt method.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your huge integer representation is going to use decimal digits, `ParseInt` is going to need to break the argument down into individual decimal digits.  Give this a try:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include "Fibonacci.h"

void hugeDestroyer(HugeInteger *p)
{
    if ( p != NULL ) {
        free( p->digits );
        free( p );
    }
}

HugeInteger *parseString(char *str)
{
    HugeInteger *huge;
    int i;

    if (str == NULL)
        goto error1;

    if ((huge = malloc(sizeof *huge)) == NULL)
        goto error1;

    huge->length = strlen(str);

    if ((huge->digits = malloc(huge->length * sizeof *huge->digits)) == NULL)
        goto error2;

    for (i = 0; i < huge->length; i++) {
        huge->digits[huge->length-i-1] =
            (str[i] >= '0' && str[i] <= '9') ? str[i] - '0' : 0;
    }

    return huge;

//error3:
//    free(huge->digits);
error2:
    free(huge);
error1:
    return NULL;
}

HugeInteger *parseInt(unsigned int n)
{
    HugeInteger *huge;
    int digits[10]; // largest 32-bit unsigned integer has 10 digits in base 10
    int length;

    if ((huge = malloc(sizeof *huge)) == NULL)
        goto error1;

    length = 0;
    do {
        digits[length++] = n % 10;
        n /= 10;
    }
    while (n);

    huge->length = length;

    if ((huge->digits = malloc(huge->length * sizeof *huge->digits)) == NULL)
        goto error2;

    memcpy(huge->digits, digits, huge->length * sizeof *huge->digits);

    return huge;

//error3:
//    free(huge->digits);
error2:
    free(huge);
error1:
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: Looking back at it now, I never handled the values passed to parseInt(), this solution works for my test case. Thank you @pat and everyone else. I will try to do a better job at handling my memory leaks next time

Answer (score 0):

I just looked at your `HugeInteger` struct and notice that `length` is not a pointer. Do not free it!

As @EricFortin mentioned, you do not initialize your struct after calling `malloc()`:

```
HugeInteger *numArray = malloc(sizeof(HugeInteger));
numArray->length = 0 ; // add me
numArray->digits = NULL ; // add me
```

Same thing here:

```
HugeInteger *number = malloc(sizeof(HugeInteger));
numArray->length = 0 ; // add me
numArray->digits = NULL ; // add me
```

Every time you return early from any of your `ParseInt()` or `ParseString()` functions, you have a memory leak because you do not free your `HugeInteger` pointer.

Do this (I was wrong the first time, another thanks to @EricFortin):

```
    for ( i = 0; i < p->length; i++) // remove me
        free( p->digits[i] ); // remove me
    free( p->digits ); // keep me
```

Comment: Thank you, major oversight on my part. Still getting the Segmentation fault though. Upon further Debugging I've Found that it goes through 10 instances of 
    for ( i = 0; i < p->length; i++)
        free( p->digits[i] );
when the array 354913546879519843519843548943513179 is passed, on the 10th pass it Seg faults even though the size of the array is 36

Comment: I get what you're saying now, I'm trying to get rid of things I haven't even initialized yet and that's making things go crazy here. 
I added the statements to initialize my Struct but now I'm getting a seg fault in the first instance of parseInt(246810)